# Tornar conteúdo de iframe responsivo (Google DFP)

Tags: javascript, html, css, google, iframe

Então, estou com um problema um tanto quanto complexo. Sabendo que não é possível estilizar com CSS o conteúdo de um `<iframe>`, não conheço outra forma de alcançar o objetivo desejado. Até tentei com JavaScript, porém nada funcionou, sendo que alguns testes eu tive o erro CrossOrigin, devido a tentar 'acessar' o conteúdo de uma URL diferente da de origem.

Estou utilizando Google DoubleClick for Business para exibir anúncios em um determinado site. Para quem não sabe o que o DoubleClick é, um AdServer. Ele gera uma tag javascript e o conteúdo resultado na página será um HTML com o que foi definido, neste caso infelizmente ele utiliza iframe, um tanto quanto defasado. O problema é que os anúncios são de tamanhos fixos (eu posso definir). O serviço não tem uma responsividade nativa, ou seja, largura 100% por exemplo. Evitando ter que cadastrar criativos de vários tamanhos diferentes, quero torná-los responsivos, consegui fazer isso com o serviço que utilizo atualmente.

> [Veja em funcionamento](https://jsfiddle.net/tiagoboeing/Lwrn4q7L/)

Tag gerada pelo DFP `<head>`

```
<script async='async' src='https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'></script>
  <script>
    var googletag = googletag || {};
    googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
  </script>

  <script>
    googletag.cmd.push(function () {
      googletag.defineSlot('/21690932511/oregionalsul.com/1200x160_featured', [[1200, 160], [970, 90]], 'div-gpt-ad-1521048007443-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
      googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
      googletag.enableServices();
    });
  </script>
```

Tag `<body>`

```
  <!-- /21690932511/oregionalsul.com/1200x160_featured -->
  <div id='div-gpt-ad-1521048007443-0'>
    <script>
      googletag.cmd.push(function () { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1521048007443-0'); });
    </script>
  </div>
```

> [Resultado esperado](http://g.recordit.co/YPnafaRlGd.gif)

Comment: Cara o correto não é ter uma peça única com 100% de largura, e sim uma peça para cada formato. Pelo menos de acordo com a documentação... Inclusive fiz uns testes com o seu anuncio e ele funciona no formato [320, 700], [300, 250] por exemplo. Isso deve responder a sua pergunta... https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/3423562?hl=pt-BR

Comment: Já cheguei a visitar esta documentação, porém várias peças para um anúncio alteram a lógica de mercado aplicada atualmente pela empresa. Por exemplo, os anúncios 800x600 serão sempre desta proporção, e sofrerão redimensionamento (100% largura e altura relativa) de acordo com a resolução. Daí é que está o grande problema, pois o DFP está defasado na questão dessas tags, atualmente com outra empresa funciona dessa forma.

Comment: Cara então faz na gambiarra mesmo, transforma a animação em GIF e usa como imagem colocando 100% na largura...

Comment: Eis o problema... Isto é um GIF animado, não é possível colocar 100% de largura pois o `<iframe>` é gerado pelo script do DFP. Qualquer mudança via CSS não afetará o conteúdo por estar dentro do ìframe` . Fiquei um bom tempo tentando forçar algumas tags, classes e ids com `!important` mas não tem jeito.

Comment: Na verdade eu quis dizer para vc capturar a animação do iFrame e converter em um Gif, tipo gravar a tela e salvar um Gif e depois usa-lo no lugar do iFrame. Na verdade vc nem usaria o iFrame nesse caso, apenas o Gif que fez a partir da animação do iFrame. Não sei se essa opção te serve...

Comment: Isso que você sugeriu seria apenas colocar o gif diretamente na página, não? Sendo assim eu ignoraria o DFP e tudo perderia a lógica, já que o objetivo do mesmo é gerenciar anúncios. O AdServer que a empresa utiliza atualmente possui opção de tags via REST API e outras, aí fica fácil trabalhar com responsividade, pois o HTML gerado é explícito com tags como divs e imgs.

Comment: Já que não é um caso em particular e sim todo um workflow acho que realmente no seu caso não faria sentido transformar a animação em Gif. Citei essa opção pq é uma prática que eu fazia quando tinha uma animação em CSS3 e queria que ela funcionasse nos Browsers antigos, ai eu convertia a animação em Gif e ficava tranquilo. Mas as vezes aparece alguém com uma resposta realmente funcional nesse caso

Comment: Fiz uma update na questão, você provavelmente entendeu errado, tenho um GIF do funcionamento atual: https://g.recordit.co/YPnafaRlGd.gif Seria simples se o DFP permitisse colocar a largura proporcional, a questão é conseguir forçar a injeção do script a isso.

Comment: Pode ser em jQuery?

Comment: Resolvendo o problema será muito bem válido. De fácil implementação na página de preferência.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro adicione no seu CSS:

```
iframe{
   width: 100% !important;
}
```

Solução em jQuery usando `contents()`:

```
$(window).on("load", function(){
   $("iframe").on("load", function(){
      var ads = $(this).contents().find("#aw0 img");
      ads.attr({
         "width": "100%",
         "height": "auto"
      });
   });
});
```

**[Veja no JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwrn4q7L/37/)**

Solução usando JavaScript puro:

```
window.onload = function(){

   var iframe = document.body.querySelector("iframe");

   iframe.onload = function(){
      var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document,
      ads = iframeDocument.body.querySelector("#aw0 img");

      ads.style.cssText = "width: 100%; height: auto;";
   }

}
```

**[Veja no JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwrn4q7L/36/)**

Comment: Já chequei no celular e a princípio está funcionando lindamente. Assim que estiver no computador irei realizar a implantação e caso resolva atribuo como melhor resposta. Agradeço antecipadamente por se dispor a ajudar.

Comment: Blz amigo! Boa sorte!

Comment: Fiz alguns testes, somente em um documento `.html` localmente não funciona, upando o mesmo para o servidor, sem outros conteúdos juntamente, funciona legal. Agora estou sofrendo um pouco para descobrir se há conflitos ou realmente não funciona em uma página. Veja: https://vargemdocedro.oregionalsul.com/ O iframe está responsivo ao que parece, porém o conteúdo não é afetado nesta página.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada...

Comment: Te uns conflitos na página... dentro do style.css tem uns `@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700);`... altere para `https` e veja se `http` em outros lugares tb e altere

Comment: Alterado, porém como imaginava, não afetou o conteúdo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74881/discussion-between-dvd-and-tiago-boeing).